# Removing duplicate rows from a CSV file using a python script and update this CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a `myfile.csv` with rows like

```
first, second, third
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
```

and so on.

I don't understand how to remove duplicate rows in `myfile.csv`.

One condition, we can't save new files, we need to update `myfile.csv`.
In order to after run script `myfile.csv` look like

```
first, second, third
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
```

So new data is not saved to a new file need of updating `myfile.csv`.
Thank you very much.

Comment: How big is the CSV file (number of rows)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply and short with **`pandas`** module:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 9):

You can loop over the data and filter the lists to contain only unique values:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))
  new_data = [a for i, a in enumerate(data) if a not in data[:i]]
  with open('filename.csv', 'w') as t:
     write = csv.writer(t)
     write.writerows(new_data)
```